# Preview in xml design does not show completely

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

This is what I see in preview mode
[image]

As you can see, since my first `TextView` (tv1) is too high, so it pushes the second `TextView` (tv2) out of screen. How can I see everything in my layout in preview mode?

I came up with some ideas like `setVisibility` of tv1 to `Gone` or wrap my root view inside a `ScrollView` so I can scroll in preview mode (but it changes the layout structure). This there a better way to make it?

**Note:** I just make an example. In fact, my layout can be much higher, so change the device in preview mode isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the preview screen with stretch this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change your device in preview.

[image]

in your case, it look like this.

[image: add image]

but it can be different with real devices

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check how it looks without adding ScrollView then. Just Change device preview. Currently, your device preview is using Pixel device now change it to 10' tablet so might be you can preview your full view.

Comment: I just make an example. In fact, my layout can be much higher, so change the device in preview mode isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ScrollView` and set the height of tv1 and tv2 to `layout_height =" wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are given 
`android:orientation="Vertical"` in linear layout

and `android:layout-height:"800dp"` in Text View

Can you click and drag below of preview // icon to increase length...